# Vuex ID generator

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to generate unique IDs for my components.

I thought, since it's global, it would be good to put this in Vuex, with a field like `lastGeneratedID: 0` in the state, and a mutation that increments this value.

Now when a component wants to have a new ID, it has to read the value first and then increment, ALWAYS in this oder, ALWAYS perform both operations or else things get messy.

Is there a way I can somehow centralise these two in one function (preferably not just on the `$root` instance) or should I just not do this kind of thing?

Or should I just name the field `lastGeneratedIDAlwaysHasToBeIncrementedAfterReadingDontYouDareNotIncrementing`? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just call the mutation first, to increment the id and then read it. JS is single threaded, so you can't have racing conditions.

```
this.$store.commit('INCREMENT_ID')

const myId = this.$store.state.id
```

You could package both lines in another function and only call that one.

```
export default getNewID = () => {
 store.commit('INCREMENT_ID')

 return store.state.id
}
```

I'm assuming that you're exporting this from a package and also `import` store.

An alternative would be to generate a unique id, so you don't need to keep track of generated ids. You could use a uuid package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4)

Comment: Because I can't guarantee that me and my co-workers will always think of the right order or will even call both operations. Thanks for the package link anyway, that sounds easier!

Comment: Then package this in another function and only call that one.

Comment: But where should I put that function in a normal Vue setup? I don't wanna put it in the `$root` component and you can't add functions to Vuex, I also don't want anything that only returns promises like actions

Comment: Create a new js file and export it. In my answer I've used a default export, but you could use a named one. Then import that package anywhere you need it.